# Karate UI Initial Get Call to BrowserStack Failing

Tags: karate, junit5, java-11, browserstack, webdriver-w3c-spec

I'm attempting to do a POC for our mobile browser automation testing using Karate UI and BrowserStack.  I noticed Karate attempts to make a GET call to BrowserStack when the test starts, and is receiving a 500:

```
GET https://user:key@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub
31 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
31 > Connection: Keep-Alive
31 > Host: hub-cloud.browserstack.com
31 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/11.0.7)

12:18:18.140 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 152.10
31 < 500
31 < Connection: keep-alive
31 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
31 < Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 19:18:18 GMT
31 < Server: nginx
31 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
31 < accept: application/json
{"value":{"message":"Invalid Command"}}
```

As you can see running Java 11.  Also running Junit5.  Here's my setup so far(username and key have been replaced for security):

```
Background:

  * def session = {capabilities: {deviceName: 'iPhone X', platformName: 'iOS', browserName: 'safari'}, desiredCapabilities: {deviceName: 'iPhone X', platformName: 'iOS', browserName: 'safari'}}
  * configure driver = {type: 'chrome', webDriverSession: '#(session)', start: false, webDriverUrl: 'http://user:key@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub'}
```

And the stacktrace from the Karate report.  Thinking it might be complaining about the `session` variable?  I followed the Karate setup, the browserstack setup, and the W3C webdriver docs.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: consumer.feature:13 - driver config / start failed: class net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to class java.util.List (net.minidev.json.JSONObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'), options: {type=chrome, webDriverSession={capabilities={deviceName=iPhone X, platformName=iOS, browserName=safari}, desiredCapabilities={deviceName=iPhone X, platformName=iOS, browserName=safari}}, start=false, webDriverUrl=http://user:key@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:109)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit5.FeatureNode.lambda$next$0(FeatureNode.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$0(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:52)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptDynamicTest(InvocationInterceptor.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$1(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoid$0(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:76)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicTestTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicTestTestDescriptor.java:31)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:442)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.execute(DynamicContainerTestDescriptor.java:33)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:198)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$1(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestFactoryTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestFactoryTestDescriptor.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

UPDATE:  Am able to run the basic Java test using the same Maven project, so likely the issue lies somewhere in Junit or Karate.
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to attempting to run without a grid setup.  Once I added Zalenium, was able to run the test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with BrowserStack; however, there is a mismatch when you are passing 'browserName' as 'safari' in session and driver type is 'chrome'. One more thing to try is that you need to specify driver type as 'ios' and you probably don't need to provide 'browserName' if you are looking for device node on browserstack. 
https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities

Comment: Per W3C doc it seems that iOS should go with `platformName` as I have it set:
https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities
I believe chrome is to run browserstack, and safari to run the site under test, unless I'm mis-understanding the Karate and W3C docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the Hub URL with your local setup and check if that works post which you can use BrowserStacks Hub URL.

Comment: Tried looking at the local setup instructions for browserstack, the Java specific ones use a file type that doesn't seem to be true Java.  Repo hasn't been updated in a while, and as I'm not a programmer, this response looks to require more work than doing the full setup, which I was trying to avoid.