# Can someone share a sample project for integration of Karate with BrowserStack for Mobile app automation

Tags: mobile, automation, karate, browserstack

My team and I have been trying to integrate Karate with Browserstack for our Mobile UI automation, but it has not worked till now. Can someone share a sample\example project.

We have been successfully using Karate for API and web UI automation till now.

Regards,
saurabh goel

Comment: Not sure what your stuck on as you haven't provided any details, but if it's like my issue, it's super basic to fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351766/karate-ui-initial-get-call-to-browserstack-failing

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this project as a reference: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-devicefarm-demo - and then try to get support from the BrowserStack team or do your own research.

In case it matters, note that Karate only supports the W3C WebDriver spec and not the old wire-protocol. For an example of what problems this can cause, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644566/143475

There are other answers on Stack Overflow that may give you some pointers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67066287/143475 |
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992292/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter, let me go through this and will update here once we have the solution. Have a nice day!